# Changing consumer configs for Kafka Connect workers

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm facing issues with the HDFS SInk Connector for Kafka Connect. It gets caught in an infinite loop of rebalancing. According to one of the discussions on the connector's github page, one possible solution is to make some changes to the consumer configs. For example

```
session.timeout.ms=10000
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
request.timeout.ms=1810000
max.poll.interval.ms=1800000
```

However my problem is that I do not know where to do this. My understanding is that consumer configs are configured in the application which is doing the consuming, but I do not see any reference to these configs in the source code.

If I add these to the sink connector's configuration file, then restart the connect task, I can see from the logs that the above configurations remain unchanged.

If I add them to the connect-distributed.properties, and then restart the worker and the task, I can see from the logs that the above configurations remain unchanged.

Where do I set these in order for them to be picked up by Kafka-Connect?

Comment: @cricket_007 any advise?

Comment: bonus if you can tell me how to do this with Confluents Helm Charts for Kafka Connect

Comment: It has to be a part of connect-distributed.properties if you are running Kafka connect in distributed mode. Once you make changes across all workers across different nodes(not only one), restart all of them at once. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the connect-distributed.properties config file, the way to set the consumer configs is to preappend 'consumer.' to each config (or 'producer.' for producer configs)

So

```
session.timeout.ms=10000
```

becomes

```
consumer.session.timeout.ms=10000
```

When working with Confluents (not yet production ready) Helm charts for Kafka Connect a few changes are required. First of all, all additional configs need to be put in the customEnv section of the values.yaml. Second each config you wish to set here must be written all in caps, with '.' replaced by '_'. Third of all, each config needs to be preappended with 'CONNECT_'

So

```
session.timeout.ms=10000
```

becomes

```
CONNECT_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 10000
```

This is just for the consumers that start automatically with the workers.

An additional change is required for the consumers that start with the tasks. After 'CONNECT_', you must place 'CONSUMER_'. (For producer configs, you need to use 'PRODUCER_')

So

```
session.timeout.ms=10000
```

becomes

```
CONNECT_CONSUMER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 10000
```

Comment: It did. It was a while ago now, but I remember being satisfied with this, while also being frustrated at how hidden within the documentation these requirements were.

Comment: Part about documentation is indeed frustrating unfortunately.